Remove blank space in a Dash Plotly dropdown menu?
I'm trying to create a Dash Plotly app in Python. When I create a dropdown menu, it looks like this:
Screenshot
I've tried resizing and aligning the object in different ways, but all of them have the same problem. So far, I've tried wrapping the dropdown in a html.Div, html.Center, and dbc.Container (Rows and Cols as well). All of them produce the same result.
What can I do?
Sample code:
app.layout = [
    html.Center(
        [
            html.H1("Iris Graph Test"),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                options=dropdown_options,
                value=dropdown_options[0],
                id="dropdown",
                style={"max-width": "50%"},
            ),
            html.Div(id="graphs"),
        ]
    )
]


Solved it by adding an external stylesheet to the Dash constructor and using dbc.Col. I have no idea why this works.
What I was doing before:
app = Dash()

And then after:
# Any theme in dbc.themes works
app = Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

Then, shrink the Dropdown by using the width arg in dbc.Col.
dbc.Col( <Dropdown>, width=<int> )

If you try to shrink the Dropdown (or any object, really) without a stylesheet, every object forces the Col to be the width of the window. Trying to shrink the dropdown with any html object always adds the blank white space next to the options.
I'm no expert, so please feel free to correct me here. But, anyway, this has the intended effect of shrinking my dropdown menu without adding the blank white space on the left of the options.
New result screenshot: 
